# How to deploy a WPF application?

Tags: wpf, deployment

I have developed a WPF application and deployed it using Click Once Deployment. I installed it on another pc it works fine but the problem is that the application's root folder is being created in a temporary folder in app data/local. I want to give user the flexibility of installing the software wherever he/she wants. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You simply can't change the installation folder using ClickOnce. If you want to do this you need to choose a different installer technology.

ClickOnce application require no administrative privileges and are always installed per user in the user application cache.