# control directory where wpf application is getting installed

Tags: wpf, clickonce

I am using clickonce for deploying WPF application.

But when user installs using exe file which I published, it gets installed inside some random directory on user's machine.

Is there way to control path of directory where published application will get installed on user machine?

Thanks,
Pankaj

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deploy a WPF application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41760548/how-to-deploy-a-wpf-application)

Answer (score 1):

ClickOnce's purpose is to install the app into a sandboxed location in the user's profile.

If you need to control where your application is installed, you need to use a different packaging and installation mechanism like [Microsoft VisualStudio 2015 Installer Projects](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudio2015InstallerProjects) or  InstallShield LE.